# Generate unique random binary arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, random, binary

I want to generate 200 random binary arrays of size 30, but I need all of them to be unique! I use to following to generate the arrays:

```
import numpy as np

parents = []
for i in range(200):
    parents.append(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(30)))
parents = np.vstack(parents)
```

Are the arrays made in this way already unique (if so, how may I check that)? If not, how do I modify my code so I get unique arrays?

Comment: No, they are not, and there are 0 guarantees that they ever will be. Your best bet is to deterministically generate unique rows and then permute them.

Comment: you can generate them and then compare all arrays for non-unique occurrences to replace them with a new random array. Since 200<2^30 there should be plenty of cases. This way your arrays will be "guaranteed" to be unique

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for your comment! if I use permute/shuffle command in a loop, it will automatically result in unique arrays? Even if this is true, the issue herein is that, regardless the arrays are uniqe, I will be generating arrays in which the number of 1s and 0s are exactly the same (like 5 ones and 25 zeroes). Do you have any idea how I can cope with that?

Comment: @anishtain4 True, but how I may find the similar arrays, and how I may replace them with some new arrays that are not already in my list is my question indeed!!

Comment: What is your uniqueness condition? Are they assumed to be sets or lists, i.e. are `[0,1]` and `[1,0]` the same arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the length is large enough, the probability of generating two equal arrays is very low. Rejection sampling will be very fast:

```
import numpy as np

parents = set()
while len(parents) < 200:
    a = tuple(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(30)))
    if a not in parents: parents.add(a)
parents = np.array([list(x) for x in parents])
```

And also, using set() for membership check is faster than arrays.

Answer (score 4):

They are not unique, since if they were, then they would not be uniformly random each time.

You could perform a quick check each time you generate a new array, and make sure it is unique (using set lookups rather than array lookups for larger parent arrays):

```
parents = []
for i in range(200):
    unique_found = False
    while not unique_found:
        candidate_array = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(30))
        if not any((candidate_array == x).all() for x in parents):
            unique_found = True
    parents.append(candidate_array)
```

However, since there are 1,073,741,824 unique binary arrays of length 30, the probability of getting 2 or more duplicates is:

1 - (1 - (1/1,073,741,824)) ^ (200 choose 2) = 0.0000185, or about 1 time of every 54,000.

So you might be ok with ignoring the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the following error when I run your code: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: Oops, forgot we were using numpy arrays. It'd look something like: `not any((candidate_array == x).all() for x in parents`

Comment: thanks! Could you please explain how you calculated that probability too?! Or at least give me a hint/reference so I can find out how to do so if you do not mind?!

Comment: Sure! It's the same as the birthday problem, which is very well documented: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem